# Vagrant port not exposed

Tags: django, vagrant, read-the-docs

I am using an `ubuntu/xenial64` vagrant box and following the instructions indicated [here](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) to set up a `readthedocs` server.

I am also hard coding a static private net IP in `Vagrantfile`:

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

However, after starting the `Django` server:

```
(rtd) vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org$ python manage.py runserver
[14/Mar/2018 05:22:40] root:120[1581]: INFO Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[14/Mar/2018 05:22:40] root:120[1581]: INFO Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[14/Mar/2018 05:22:41] root:120[1585]: INFO Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[14/Mar/2018 05:22:41] root:120[1585]: INFO Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.
?: (guardian.W001) Guardian authentication backend is not hooked. You can add this in settings as eg: `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend')`.

System check identified 2 issues (1 silenced).
March 14, 2018 - 05:22:42
Django version 1.9.12, using settings 'readthedocs.settings.dev'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I am unable to access `http://192.168.33.10:8000/`

Within the `vagrant` machine:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ netstat -ta
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:8000          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          *:*                     LISTEN
```

Using

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 2.0.2
```

and `Virtualbox 5.2.8 r121009 (Qt5.6.1)` on `Ubuntu 16.04.03` host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is detailed at the end of the document

> For builds to properly kick off as expected, it is necessary the port
>   you’re serving on (i.e. `runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`) match the port defined
>   in `PRODUCTION_DOMAIN`. You can utilize `local_settings.py` to modify
>   this. (By default, it’s `localhost:8000`)

You can do one of the two:

- start the server with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`
- update `local_settings.py` and change `localhost:8000` with `0.0.0.0:8080`

You can also replace `0.0.0.0` with the IP you've configured for the VM

Comment: thanks that did the job; after starting up the web ui however and trying to login using my `Django` superuser account, it is asking me to verify my email address (which I cannot of course given that this local instance is not connected to any mail server). Can I log in without mail verification?

Comment: right, I am not familiar to connecting Django with a local mail server, you should probably create another post for this, if there's not one already for the same topic